# Hide/Show icons with long press in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, long-press

I have a ListView in my application.

Each row has an icon (left), a title (center) and some icons like delete or share (right). I want that when the user **long press** on any item, these icons are not visible and **CheckBox** appears to the right of the row (in this place) that allow the user to mark the items he wants.

This is for individual actions (delete, share) in normal mode and global actions to multiple files simultaneously (icons in the action bar and checkBox) long press mode. Similar to the Android gallery.

So I have the following code:

```
   list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           aDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           aShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
           return false;
       }       
   });
```

But my application crashes because I think I can not do this with the interface execution in main thread.

My LogCat errors:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.adapta.FileExplorer$2.onItemLongClick(FileExplorer.java:182)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2815)
at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2765)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: what is your line 182?

Comment: May your aDelete or aShare or check could be null at that time? There is no restriction about that

Comment: @KryNaC Have you initialized __aElim__ variable? Something like **aElim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.youbutton)**

Comment: Yes, in OnCreate method I have "aDelete = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.aDelete);"

Comment: My line 182 is "aDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);"

Comment: I think that it can be because I can not delete something is showing the interface at that time ...

Comment: I could be that I have an 'aDelete' icon in each item (row) of ListView and when I put "aDelete.setVisibility(VIew.GONE);" there are some icons with the same ID ... ¿?¿?

Comment: I have found a solution, I had to put "aDelete = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.aDelete);" before than "aDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);" and not in onCreate method where it is 'null'. But now I have another problem, it only is gone the icon first row and not all icons of ListView ... all icons have the same name (R.id.aDelete)